# serial port is hostage of writer thread

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux, rtai

I have two real-time threads(linux)

First one is to send bytes over serial port (kernel space)

Second one is to read the same bytes(because i used loop-back device) from serial port.

First thread sends data continuously and asynchronously, however;

second thread cannot open the serial port to read..

I used semaphores, but my problem i guess.. is not the synchronization issue,
my problem is serial port still in the hand of first thread.

How can I overcome this issue..

I am open to your suggestions,

Best Regards

Comment: When you open your device are you opening it in Read/Write mode, or each one in Read mode only and the other in Write mode only?

Comment: each one in read mode only, and the other in Write mode only (so means two different code scripts, both on kernel space)

Comment: So you mean each one is opened in Read/Write, and the other is opened it Write only? If so I don't think this is possible, as the device pipe can only be opened and accessed through a single handle.

Comment: briefly, first one is write only, second one is read only, however when i compile and insmod read only one, it says "adress in use -98" as a reply for rt_spopen..

Comment: writing side works properly, but i cannot read. I use loop-back connector at my COM1.

Comment: @Preston, can it be the reason I pass the char arrays into sp_read_timed function wrongly..I am looking how to pass char array into a function

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough information to be for sure. You might update your question to post some code samples so that everyone can see what's happening.

Comment: *"second thread cannot open the serial port to read"* -- Besides showing your code, you need to fully describe the symptoms you saw that lead you to this assumption (i.e. what is the *errno*?).

Comment: @sawdust one of them is; Error: rt_spopen and Adress in use -98; On the other hand I was thinking how to minimize my code to post here.. thats why i still couldnt post...

Comment: @sawdust http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568883/serial-port-cannot-read-what-i-write i updated my issue right here

Comment: Why not open your port in read & write by one of the kernel modules, then in the second one just call the `rt_spread`, assuming the port is already open (which it is).

Comment: thank you @Shahbaz , what I did was to use two different ports that are buried into a  desktop case